# Replace Zorin by Ubuntu in dual booting system 2

Tags: dual-boot, updates, 16.04, windows-10

I have dual booted my Lenovo laptop with Zorin OS alongside Windows 10. Now I am planning to install Ubuntu 16.04 and replace Zorin.

Will my Windows partition be affected? 
Will I be able to update my Ubuntu partition?

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from Ubuntu Installation media.
2. Unmount any mounted drives if they exist.
3. Proceed to Step 4. Choose "Something else" and click "Continue"
   [image]

The partition table will look like this:
[image]

Free some space for Ubuntu:

- Select the *Zorin OS* drive (not the loader!).
- Check "Format the partition" checkbox. and check the file correspondant system for Ubuntu[image]
- If you want, you can delete some partitions. This is done by clicking -"*Change..*" button. Do not delete Windows partition.

Now your partition table is ready to install Ubuntu in the Zorin partition after you format it, then you can continue the installation process after

Comment: Do i need to remove the present bootloader since the ubuntu installation will install a new bootloader (grub)?

Comment: That will be automatically updated, so you don't need to remove it.